# Azure Logic Apps to ServiceNow connector: User Not Authenticated

Tags: azure-logic-apps, servicenow

We are connecting to a customer ServiceNow instance using Azure Logic Apps and a ServiceNow connector. We are able to connect to ServiceNow instance using a browser with same user name and password.

When trying to connect using Logic Apps and the ServiceNow connector, it gives the below error. Please advise if any specific roles / privileges are required to be given to this user in ServiceNow for the connector to work?

```
Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again.  
Details: User Not Authenticated. Client request id: '034764FB-B8C2-4BBA-852D-C266827C1594'
```

Comment: How are you configuring authentication on the ServiceNow connector?

Comment: Through username and password as per document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/service-now/

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue as you did when using my ServiceNow account credentials in the Logic App fields. To successfully connect, I had to follow these steps after creating an instance:

1. Go to https://developer.servicenow.com
2. Choose the instance menu in the top right.
3. In the dropdown that opens, choose 'Manage instance password':
   [image: My Instance menu]
4. In the 'Manage instance password' window that opens, you will see the login credentials for your instance. *This is what you need to copy into the Logic App ServiceNow connector  to authenticate*.
   [image]